# How to serialize subitem using json.net & c#

Tags: json.net, subitem

How can i serialize using json.net & c#?
what is best way?
How to append child node?
output json string like this :

{
"OptQty":100,"OptQtySpecified":false,
"OptTextList":
[{"SiteStockTextNo":1634245835,"DescriptiveText":"TextStyle","DisplayIs":true,"ChangeType":1}],
"OptSel":{"OptRepImageLevel":0,"OptRepImageLevelSpecified":true,"SortOrder":1,
"ObjOptInfo":{"ObjOptNo1":0,"ObjOptClaseNm1":"fileds1","ObjOptClaseNm5":""},
"Calculation":null,
"StockList":
[
{"SiteStockNo":1633316906,"Text1":"abcd","Text2":"PK7701","Qty":0,"Price":14500,"SoldOutIs":true},
{"SiteStockNo":1633316907,"Text1":"abcd","Text2":"PK7702","Qty":0,"Price":12500,"SoldOutIs":false},
{"SiteStockNo":1633316908,"Text1":"abcd","Text2":"PK7703","Qty":0,"Price":12500,"SoldOutIs":false},
{"SiteStockNo":1633316915,"Text1":"abcd","Text2":"PK7711","Qty":0,"Price":2500,"SoldOutIs":false}
]
},
"OptAdd":null
}

Comment: You already have the serilaized Json string. what u want to do?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
A simple Employee object:

public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }   
}

Adding some instances of them to a List:

Employee oEmployee1 = 
       new Employee{Name="Pini",ID="111", Age="30"};

Employee oEmployee2 = 
      new Employee { Name = "Yaniv", ID = "Cohen", Age = "31" };
Employee oEmployee3 = 
        new Employee { Name = "Yoni", ID = "Biton", Age = "20" };

List<Employee> oList = new List<Employee>() 
{ oEmployee1, oEmployee2, oEmployee3 };

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = 
         new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(oList);
```